# How do I save a long GMail html ad as an image?

Tags: gmail, html, capture

I would like to save an html ad for posting but posting it long form on a Google+, Tumblr, or Wordpress blog easily.

I saw a very similar question to this here:

[How do I save an image of a really long website? Taking about millions of pixels in height](https://superuser.com/questions/686617/how-do-i-save-an-image-of-a-really-long-website-taking-about-millions-of-pixels)

"Journeyman Geek" posted an interesting experimental feature in that link about my browser Mozilla firefox.

The text within an html image saved in this method rendered better than any snapshot utility I have seen but it didn't save a long- otherwise "scrollable" html advertisement/image and it made a 5mm white border around the whole image.

The html ad was junkmail so I have no reservations about reposting it in full view of the internet.

Can I save it as a PDF and upload it to a free Scribd blog/account for viewing?

Thanks.

Jay

Comment: When you say long Ads, how long are you talking about. Most ads should fit into a single screen and wouldn't require scrolling. In such cases you can simply use any screen capture tools to capture the image out of it. For instance, on windows you can use the inbuilt "Snipping Tool". ** Note: ** I don't understand if that is what you are looking for. Your question header and description conveys two different things!.

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: Have you ever opened up an email using gmail to find a general advertisement aka spam? Have you ever found it to be all in html  (vs. text)?  Most of them involve scrolling down as GMails inbox requires at least 1/5 of head room. The bulk of snipping tools notoriously do not copy within frames. My question to the user base here is, "has anyone found a free to nominal solution for capturing the entire HTML advertisement"? I would like to repost it on a blog platform (see above). Picture a clickable thumbnail where you can read it in full if desired. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll down whilst capturing an image like snipper tool

Hope [this](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) helps.